# What are Best Practices for using Flutter with Pusher Notifications?

Tags: laravel, flutter, pusher

I'm trying to create desktop app with Flutter. I'm using [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) as backend with [Pusher notifications](https://pusher-community.github.io/real-time-laravel/).  What is the best way to integrate Pusher notifications in the Flutter desktop app?

Comment: The page you linked to describes Pusher as being for "web and mobile applications"; is there a reason you believe it supports native desktop applications?